# each() function not in the DOM, delegeta problems jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, each

I want to display the `alert()` after a new row is appended.

This is my code, but delegation is not working.

```js
$(".tweet").each(function() {
  alert("tweet alert");
});

$("button").click( function(){
    $("#container").append("<div class='tweet'>tweet</div>");
    
    
});


$(document).delegate('click', function(){
    $(this).addClass("tweet");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="container"></div>
<button>Create</button>
```

Im using a basic jquery version `1.4`

In my code, the alert doesnt display at all! what am doing wrong? thank you.

Comment: Why using `1.4`? and why not add alert in button click handler when you append the div?

Comment: 1.4, because I want a fast plugin load, and till now I dont need mor for my codes

Comment: what is that about adding a click handler?

Answer (score 0):

You can add the alert inside the click handler like so:

```js
$("button").click(function() {
  $("#container").append("<div class='tweet'>tweet</div>");
  alert("tweet alert");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
<button>Create</button>
```

Comment: no, I want the each() function has the `alert()` because this is a more complex code

Comment: This will work only for elements that already exist. Not new ones

Comment: this is my problem, mate. I need to make those new elements work